# How to link sing in to new page

Tags: firebase, swiftui

Once I have signed into my app I display ext saying signed in but I want to link it to a new view in a separate file

How can I do this?

Sign in simplified page ...

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            if viewModel.signedIn{
                VStack{
                    Text("Signed In")//I would like this to go to a homepage and not just say text
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.signOut()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Sign Out")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .background(Color(.green))

                            
                    })
                }
                
                
            }
            else{
                SignInView()
            }

    }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.signedIn = viewModel.isSignedIn
        }
    }
        
}
```

How can I active this whilst still being able to access my sign out button

Answer (score 0):

Use [NavigationLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) programatically, from apple docs:

> Optionally, you can use a navigation link to perform navigation
> programmatically. You do so in one of two ways:

```
@State private var shouldShowPurple = false
```

> Then you can modify the purple navigation link to bind to the state
> variable:

```
NavigationLink(
    "Purple",
    destination: ColorDetail(color: .purple),
    isActive: $shouldShowPurple)
```

In your case, `isSignedIn` should be used in `isActive` to trigger the navigation.